# How to check if a port is open for remote system(ubuntu)

Tags: port

Is it possible to check that if the ports are open for the remote system on ubuntu server?

I should able to check if a port(eg:ssh) on my machine is open for the remote machine.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

use good old telnet:

```
[user@lappie ~]$ telnet host 22
Trying ip.adr.tld ...
Connected to host  (ip.addr.tld).
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
```

this is a successful attempt. An unsuccessful one should look like this;

```
[user@lappie ~]$ telnet host 23
Trying ip.adr.tld ...
telnet: connect to address ip.adr.tld: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

or with nmap

```
[user@lappie ~]$ nmap host

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2010-10-07 11:25 CEST
Nmap scan report for host (ip.adr.tld)
Host is up (0.0052s latency).
rDNS record for ip.adr.tld : host.domain.tld
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
3000/tcp open  ppp
5666/tcp open  nrpe

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.18 seconds
```

Comment: Great help!. I felt It's only listing the port no's for which the services are running on the specified host. I checked it stopping the services and running nmap command again. so it didn't list the port which I stopped. Is it really showing the open ports for remote machine?

Comment: @user53864: you should run this test on a remote machine, obviously.

Comment: This will only work for TCP services.

Comment: Using `nmap` on aws machine trigger an abuse report.

Answer (score 17):

This is simple as :

```
nc -zw3 domain.tld 22 && echo "opened" || echo "closed"
```

`-w3` is the timeout

Comment: nc -vzw3 domain.tld 22 is shorter and might be a bit more informative...

Answer (score 10):

Use NMAP. Example:

> nmap example.com

You can use IP address in place of domain name. Here is the full documentation: http://nmap.org/book/man.html

Comment: Its only listing the ports on which services are running on a specified machine.

Comment: Then you're using it wrong.

Comment: @user53864, that is correct. More specifically, it will list all OPEN ports and also describe what services are using them. If you are looking for a specific port, try simply "nmap example.com 22" as natxo asenjo said, which will scan port 22 (SSH) to see if it is open.

Answer (score 7):

From this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168317/check-status-of-one-port-on-remote-host):

> You seem to be looking for a port scanner such as nmap or netcat, both of which are available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.
>
> For example, check for telnet on a known ip:
>
> ```
>   nmap -A 192.168.0.5/32 -p 23
> ```
>
> For example, look for open ports from 20 to 30 on host.example.com:
>
> ```
>   nc -z host.example.com 20-30
> ```

Answer (score 6):

For a script, I use something like the following:

```
nmap example.com -p 22 -sV --version-all -oG - | grep -iq '22/open'
```

The return value tells you whether the port is open!

Answer (score 2):

nmap example.com -p 22

Answer (score 2):

Telnet will only work for TCP services, so if you're trying to see if your DHCP server (UDP/68) is running on a remote machine it won't work. Likewise nmap defaults to only scanning TCP ports.

For UDP ports use:

`nmap -sU example.com -p 68`

Answer (score 1):

I used following command .It gave output what I wanted.
`nmap -A IPAddressOfRemoteSystem -p portNumber`
ex : `nmap -A 192.168.1.87 -p 8080`
(or)
we can check the local ports also

before that first check what are the ports are open/listen mode by using following command.

`netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`

after that

`nmap -A localhost -p portNumber`

and close any one port for example if mysql is running on 3306 you can stop it by,

`sudo service mysql stop`

and then,

`nmap -A localhost -p 3306`

Hope this will helpfull.